# Error "expected string or bytes-like object" when using regex function in python

Tags: python

I am trying to use the regex function so that I replace the `}` value if it exists in the 2nd value of each list. i know there is an option to use replace as well but i was getting an error.

What i've tried so far below but i keep getting  "expected string or bytes-like object":

```
data = [["S00003", "12"], ["S00003", "4}"], ["S00003", "5}"], ["S00003", "10"], ["S00003", "6}"]]

data1 = (re.sub(r"}", "", d) for d in data)

# data1 is a list generator so i convert back to list with data2

data2 = list(data1)

print(data2)
```

expected output is:

```
data1 = [["S00003", "12"], ["S00003", "4"], ["S00003", "5"], ["S00003", "10"], ["S00003", "6"]]
```

anyone know where i'm messing up?

Comment: `for d in data` in this case `d` is a list. Maybe you were meant to do: `data1 = (re.sub(r"}", "", entry) for d in data for entry in d)`?

Comment: ahhh i see so for each element within d the list, replace }! makes sense! thanks!

Comment: No problem, added an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need nested for loops as you have lists inside of lists, currently when you loop through, your `d` is a list, and that is why the error is being thrown since you need a string object. Perhaps try using:

```
data1 = [[re.sub(r"}", "", e) for e in d] for d in data]
```

Also taking advantage of list comprehension,

Output:

`[['S00003', '12'], ['S00003', '4'], ['S00003', '5'], ['S00003', '10'], ['S00003', '6']]`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it:

```
import re

data = [["S00003", "12"], ["S00003", "4}"], ["S00003", "5}"], ["S00003", "10"], ["S00003", "6}"]]
data1 = [re.sub(r"}", "", entry) for d in data for entry in d]
print(data1)
```

Result:

```
['S00003', '12', 'S00003', '4', 'S00003', '5', 'S00003', '10', 'S00003', '6']
```